# I can not update table. how should i write to update table

Tags: mysql

```
update kothari_kem.companyinfo ci 
set ci.viewsource = "" 
where ci.recid in (
    SELECT c.recid 
    FROM kothari_kem.companyinfo c 
    where (c.contactperson = NULL or c.contactperson = "") 
    AND (c.viewsource = NULL or c.viewsource = "Y")
)
```

Comment: Do you get some error? What's wrong?

Comment: yes i get error 
You can't specify target table 'ci' for update in FROM clause
error number 1093

Comment: Don't use `=` to compare with null.  Use `is NULL` instaed.

Comment: after using IS NULL problem remain same

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tt (id INT);
INSERT INTO tt
    SELECT c.recid 
    FROM kothari_kem.companyinfo c 
    where (c.contactperson IS NULL or c.contactperson = "") 
    AND (c.viewsource IS NULL or c.viewsource = "Y");
UPDATE kothari_kem.companyinfo ci 
SET ci.viewsource = "" 
WHERE ci.recid in
    (SELECT id FROM tt)
```

Anyway, I think your query could be rewritten as

```
UPDATE kothari_kem.companyinfo ci 
SET ci.viewsource = "" 
WHERE (ci.contactperson IS NULL or ci.contactperson = "") 
  AND (ci.viewsource IS NULL or ci.viewsource = "Y")
```